# Gradient curve of a harmonic function

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, geometric-group-theory

I am reading the paper "Energy of Harmonic function and Gromov proof of Stalling theorem" https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/energy.pdf

I have no clue about the lemma 8.4(i). What is gradient curve of a harmonic function? Can anyone please give me a bit more descriptive proof or at least refer me to material required to understand this proof.

Comment: I try to give a explanation of the above question but not entirely sure. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140939/harmonic-function-on-manifold